# Prove that $h'(t)=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}ds$.

Tags: analysis

Let $\phi:[a,b]\times[c,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Define $h:[c,d]\to \mathbb{R},h(t)=\int_{a}^{b}\phi(s,t)ds$. Assume that $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}$ exists and is continuous on $[a, b]\times[c, b]$. Prove that $h'(t)=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}ds$.

I have tried to prove it by first differentiating $h(t)$ w.r.t $t$ but it shouldn't be that easy. Is it okay to just differentiate on $h(t)$ w.r.t $t$  directly?  Or how to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although one can use measure theory (e.g. the dominated convergence theorem) to prove this, there is however a direct approach since we are dealing with a continuous function. 
Let $t_0 \in [c,d]$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\displaystyle\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}(s,t_0)$ exists, then for each $s \in [a,b]$ there is a $\delta(t_0,s,\varepsilon)>0$ such that 
$$
\left|\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}(s,t_0)-\frac{\phi(s,t)-\phi(s,t_0)}{t-t_0}\right|< \frac{\varepsilon}{b-a} \quad \forall (s,t) \in [a,b]\times[c,d],\ |t_0-t|<\delta(t_0,s,\varepsilon).
$$
Since 
$$
[a,b]\times[c,d] \subset \bigcup_{(s,t) \in [a,b]\times[c,d]}(s-\varepsilon,s+\varepsilon)\times(t-\delta(t,s,\varepsilon),t+\delta(t,s,\varepsilon))
$$
and $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ is compact, therefore there exist 
$$
(s_1,t_1),\ldots, (s_n,t_n) \in [a,b]\times[c,d]
$$ 
such that
$$
[a,b]\times[c,d] \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n(s_i-\varepsilon,s_i+\varepsilon)\times(t_i-\delta(t_i,s_i,\varepsilon),t_i+\delta(t_i,s_i,\varepsilon)).
$$
Choosing 
$$
\delta_0(\varepsilon)=\min_{1 \le i \le n}\delta(t_i,s_i,\varepsilon),
$$ 
we have for every $t \in [c,d]$ with $|t_0-t|< \delta_0(\varepsilon)$ 
\begin{eqnarray}
\left|\int_a^b\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}(s,t_0)ds-\frac{h(t)-h(t_0)}{t-t_0}\right|&=&\left|\int_a^b\left[\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}(s,t_0)-\frac{\phi(s,t)-\phi(s,t_0)}{t-t_0}\right]ds\right|\\
&\le&\int_a^b\left|\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}(s,t_0)-\frac{\phi(s,t)-\phi(s,t_0)}{t-t_0}\right|ds\\
&\le&\int_a^b\frac{\varepsilon}{b-a}ds=\varepsilon,
\end{eqnarray}
i.e. $h$ is differentiable at $t_0 \in [c,d]$ and 
$$
h'(t_0)=\int_a^b\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}(s,t_0)ds.
$$

Comment: I have a question, is the last part somewhat of definition of a differentiable function or what? Why would you find an $\delta_o$ to prove $|...|\le\epsilon$

Comment: Yes it is! See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function for the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit.

Comment: Oh i see. I knew that definition of limit but didn't apply it to differentiablity, forgot that it is equivalent saying $\lim_{t\to t_0}\frac{h(t)-h(t_0)}{t-t_0}=f'(t_0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\phi$ is continuous and smooth (its derivative is also continuous), and since integration domain is fixed, then you can exchange integral with derivative operator.

\begin{equation}
\nonumber
\begin{array}{lcl}
h'(t) & = & \frac{\partial h}{\partial t} = \\
 & = & \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{a}^{b}\phi(s,t)ds = \\
 & = & \int_{a}^{b} \frac{\partial \phi(s,t)}{\partial t}ds & 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

This is the **Leibniz integral rule**.

Look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: Is there any theorem or proof support this statement?

Comment: The Leibniz integral rule is a theorem itself. The second link shows a proof of it.

Comment: Not to be too pedantic, but I wouldn't call $\phi$ smooth exactly: the continuity of $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}$ does not imply (for example) the continuity of $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial s}$.

Comment: that's right, I'd better to say that it is "smooth" with respect to variable $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,it's a corollary of the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.The exchange is availbale here because $\frac{\partial \phi(s,t)}{\partial t}$ is dominated by a integrable function i.e. it's upper-bound in $[a,b]\times[c,b]$.